# I updated the Android Studio to the latest version (3.6.1) and Gradle Plugin is not found now

Tags: android

In an Android application,
I updated the Android Studio to the latest version (3.6.1)

Now when Syncing Gradle, the Gradle Plugin is not found with the errors as following:

> Caused by:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.

And

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException:
>   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.

It's driving me crazy cause I change the Gradle Version and Gradle Plugin Version to several other possibilities but again the Gradle Plugin is not found with the same error

***Build.Gradle file:***

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

***And Gradle.Wrappers.Properties file:***

```
#Thu Mar 05 15:41:52 IRST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

***Edit :***
I added the following data too:

Compile Sdk version: 25
Build Tools Version: 25.0.3

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60520303/1318946

Answer (score 14):

This is what worked for me :

Open the *build.gradle* file from your app folder, it should look similar to this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

add *google()* to *repositories* in -**buildscript and allprojects** just like this :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()       // here
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()      //and here
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

In Android Studio, go to **File** -> **Project Structure..**   *[ shortcut : **Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S** ]*

In the ***Project*** tab -> Android Gradle Plugin Version -> 3.6.1 **and** Gradle Version -> 5.6.4 |||

Last, under the ***Module*** tab, make sure the compile sdk version is > 14 (ie: 25, 28 or 29..)

Answer (score 3):

In your gradle-wrapper.properties file, change the distributionUrl to:

*https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip*

The gradle-wrapper.properties file content should be like this:

```
#Wed Mar 11 00:28:24 EET 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a solution, the only thing was to return this In the built.gradle(project)

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
```

to this

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I first received the following error

```
   > Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing org.gradle.java.home in gradle.properties.
```

And for that I followed the steps below

First of all, you need to change the JDK version to 11, which you can get help from the link below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68541081/10300202

I will share the steps I have done in order

1. In `gradle.properties` in C:\Users{USER_NAME}\.gradle

set below flag for disable daemon gradle

> org.gradle.daemon=false

or run the below command :

**Windows :**

> (if not exist "%USERPROFILE%/.gradle" mkdir "%USERPROFILE%/.gradle") && (echo. >> "%USERPROFILE%/.gradle/gradle.properties" && echo org.gradle.daemon=false >> "%USERPROFILE%/.gradle/gradle.properties")

**UNIX :**

> mkdir -p ~/.gradle && echo "org.gradle.daemon=false" >> ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

2. I set the below flag in `.idea\compiler.xml`

set :

```
<project version="4">
  <component name="CompilerConfiguration">
    <bytecodeTargetLevel target="11" /> // <--- change this line
  </component>
</project>
```

3. I set the below flag in `.idea\gradle.xml`

set :

```
<project version="4">
  <component name="GradleMigrationSettings" migrationVersion="1" />
  <component name="GradleSettings">
    <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
      <GradleProjectSettings>
        <option name="testRunner" value="GRADLE" />
        <option name="distributionType" value="DEFAULT_WRAPPED" />
        <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        <option name="gradleJvm" value="Android Studio default JDK" /> // <-- this line
        <option name="modules">
          <set>
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/app" />
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/core_data" />
          </set>
        </option>
        <option name="resolveModulePerSourceSet" value="false" />
      </GradleProjectSettings>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

4. Set `languageLevel="JDK_11"` in `.idea\misc.xml`

you can also change JDK version from `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle` and set Gradle JDK to version 11

[image]

**I hope it helps you**

Answer (score 1):

I received the following error

```
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
 > Could not find gradle-api-3.6.4.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.6.4).
```

I just upgraded my gradle-wrapper.properties from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

to the newest gradle version

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Another issue: using `<TextClock>` in a layout also causes problems. Android Studio will not 'find' the layout! Workaround: comment out the  then un-comment it out. The build should now work!

Answer (score 0):

Write `google()` at top of `jcenter()` in main build.gradle file as shown below:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link from Developers site which mentions every Gradle version and it's corresponding plugin version. here [Update Gragle](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)

***More clarification for beginners:***

First you have to make sure which Gradle version you have in - for example "C:\Users\username.gradle\wrapper\dists", which you can also find in "gradle-wrapper.properties (Gradle Version)" file, in

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

then look at the Developers site for it's corresponding plugin version, which you will then modify in build.gradle (Project:your_project_name) file in

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0' }
```

finally sync your project and you're good to go, in some cases android studio may download the latest Gradle version so if this's your case, just give it a moment and it will sync and build your project after that.

Answer (score 0):

in my case this dependency was causing the issue 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation:1.3.1' when I deleted that dependency then error went out...