# When raising targetSdkVersion to 28, Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.R$string" on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, gradle, classnotfoundexception, dex

When I try to update my `targetSdkVersion` from 27 to 28, I get the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.baus_systems.inventorycount, PID: 2594
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/R$string;
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.StringResourceValueReader.<init>(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:156)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:240)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:51)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1922)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1897)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:45)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6708)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6255)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:208)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:205)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6991)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:884)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.R$string" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.baus_systems.inventorycount-y-SEoNnBinme-b9ebwn0xg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.baus_systems.inventorycount-y-SEoNnBinme-b9ebwn0xg==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.baus_systems.inventorycount-y-SEoNnBinme-b9ebwn0xg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /product/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.StringResourceValueReader.<init>(Unknown Source:4) 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:156) 
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:240) 
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:51) 
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1922) 
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1897) 
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.0.0:45) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6708) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6255) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:208) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:205) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6991) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:884)
```

This is the dependencies section of my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
//    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
//    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation('androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3')
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:17.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:16.2.4'
    implementation 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.11.0'
    // AWS Mobile Client
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true }
    // AWS Core
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.+')
    // AWS S3
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.3.+')
    // AWS Cognito
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.3.+')
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoauth:2.4.7@aar'
    //AWS Lambda
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.2.+')

    implementation project(':plugin')
}
```

I have tried updating the firebase dependencies to the latest versions (which required updating the minSdkVersion from 15 to 16), which has no effect (and I'm not sure whether this is a viable option, as I seem to remember my coworker saying something about barcode scanning not being supported if I take these versions too high). Updating all dependencies has the app crash with no error, and I haven't yet figured out which ones are to blame; I decided I would focus on this issue as much as possible instead of inviting more trouble without reason. I've tried enabling multidex a couple different ways, as I saw that suggested somewhere; none of them seem to help. There are a few other things I've tried as well, and have lost the pages for, but nothing I've tried has helped.

Any help in resolving this error would be appreciated, as I cannot update the app in the Play Store until I can upgrade to 28.

Comment: can i know what stacktrace are you getting when targetSdkVersion =29.

Comment: @JosePraveen, The stack trace looks the same if I raise it to 29, except for a few version numbers here and there that I changed while trying to find a solution. It's way too big to fit into a comment, but I can add it to the original question if you want to confirm that it's identical for yourself.

Comment: i hope you are updating the app in the play store, better try with API level 29 and add stacktrace. read this minimum [targetversion](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk)

Comment: @JosePraveen, That's the problem, I'm not able to update the app in the play store because I cannot update the app to 28.

Comment: So I decided to roll back to 27 so I could try updating all the dependencies with the targetSdkVersion in a working state, and now I keep getting the same issue in 27. I think I'm just going to try to get it working in 29 from here on out. This is driving me insane.

Comment: For what it's worth, the spot that is breaking appears to be when Firebase is loading options from internal resources, it's trying to load the resource string `com.google.android.gms.common.R.string.common_google_play_services_unknown_issue` as a default error value before trying to load the actual options via "google_app_id", but it can't find R.string in the DexPathList. If it were my code, I could fix the code that is broken, but I can't fix this code because it's in internal code.

Comment: try this workaround to fix this issue asap. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162131/8035260

Comment: @JosePraveen, None of the things I've tried with MultiDex over the past week have had any effect on the issue, including subclassing from `MultiDexApplication` and calling `MultiDex.install()` in `attachBaseContext()`. The only thing I can see there that I haven't tried is toggling Instant Run, because it doesn't appear to have a toggle in the settings anymore.

Comment: There is nonthing to do with 27, 28 or 29 SDK. It is totally the gradle and firebase problem. Take a look at this link from Android gradle https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#agp-missing-manifest

Comment: @CodingTT, Thank you, backing off on the Gradle version did fix it, and now I can run it on targetSdkVersion 29. I'm not sure if I can make an answer to this question without figuring out exactly what in the Gradle update broke it, but I can at least get my update to our customers and then investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment under the question, the issue turned to to be raising Gradle past 3.6.0, not raising targetSdkVersion. But what was the problem with Gradle?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60520303) answer led me to updating my Firebase and ObjectBox versions, which I thought had done before, but apparently not. But this led to an issue `Type androidx.appcompat.resources.R$attr is defined multiple times`, which resisted Cleans, Rebuilds, and Invalidate Caches. This was finally cleared up by [deleting the .gradle folder and Cleaning and Rebuilding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62203701).

But there was still one more issue remaining: `Invoke-customs are only supported starting with android O`. I still have no idea what that means, but setting

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

in my build.gradle, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50198499), seems to have gotten me past that.